# Prove that when performing long division for 2 integers, the resulting decimal fraction is always repeating.

Tags: number-theory

Here is the exact proof I must solve:

Prove that when the process of long division is used for 2 integers, say m and n,
then the resulting decimal fraction is always a repeating one, i.e.
m/n=an*an−1...a1*a0 [decimal point] b1...bk*c1...cp*c1...cp*c1...cp... = an*an−1... a1*a0 [decimal point] b1...bk(c1...cp).

I don't know where to begin. If m=5 and n=8, then 5/8=0.625 which is terminating. The wording of the question is confusing me.

Comment: I think that in the case of $m = 5$, $n = 8$, that the "repeating" decimal would be $0.625\overline{0}$ (where the $0$ is repeating.)

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307796/analysis-proof-for-repeating-digits-of-rational-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/how-can-i-prove-that-all-rational-numbers-are-either-terminating-decimal-or-repe

Comment: $5/8$ actually repeats in two ways: it's either $0.625$ followed by an infinite string of $0$s, or $0.624$ followed by an infinite string of $9$s.

Comment: I was wondering about that too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better statement is that the resulting decimal fraction is eventually repeating.

For example when you divide $7$ by $15$ you get $$0.466666...$$  and the repeating part is the $6$ not the $46$

The reason for this eventual repetition is that we only have finitely many possible remainders and when we continue the process of dividing eventually some remainder will happen again which causes a cycle to repeat itself.